# If Else Statements in Java

Tags: java

The program is supposed to be a user inputting his chosen category, but when I tried running it, I typed "African", the command on the else statement appeared.

```
package finalProject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lol {
    static String category;

    static Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Shang-ri La Plaza Mall Restaurant Inquiry! \n");
        System.out.println("Choose from below which cuisine do you prefer. \n" +
            "African or American");
        category = x.next();

        if (category == "African") {
             System.out.println("Options are found below with their corresponding price range. \n" +
                 "Wendy's Hamburger - P199 & Below");
        } else {
             System.out.println("Options are found below with their corresponding price range. \n" +
                 "Clawdaddy's Great American Picnic - P500 - P999 \n" +
                 "California Pizza Kitchen - P200 - P499 \n" + 
                 "Tender Bob's - P200 - P499 \n" +
                 "Steak Escape - P200 - P499 \n" +
                 "Balboa - P200 - P499 \n" +
                 "Billy Rock Bar & Restaurant - not found \n" +
                 "Clawdaddy Osteria Americana - P500 - P999 \n" +
                 "Gourmet To Go - P200 - P499 \n" +
                 "Maple - P500 - P999 \n" +
                 "Quiznos - P200 - P499 \n" +
                 "Texas Roadhouse Grill - P500 - P999");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please compare strings with equals() method ,not with ==

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
if (category.equals("African") {
```

Never, ever (ever) use `==` when comparing strings. That will test for object equality and not content (see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)).

Comment: Ohh. I might have seemed to forget that. Thank you!! I'll always keep that in mind.

Comment: Is that the way you earend you points. Concratualtion then!

Comment: My pleasure user3102003. These things are hard to know unless someone told you. Happy coding! @ChristianSchack: Earned? I answered the question...

Answer (score 0):

use

`category.equals("African");`

you are comparing string values